# Validating Form Number Type Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Hi I've got this problem. In my html code I can't seem to validate my input type "numbers". Iv'e used this code to try and validate it but it does not work

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form_name"]["number_name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("The following must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

I took this code from a web site that validates an input type "text" not numbers. I'm trying to implement a working "number" validation to my full html code. Btw this a sample of my form:

```
<form action = "test.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return validateForm()" name ="form_name">
<input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "0" name = "number_name" size = "2"/>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to use the javascript valdiation above to validate the number form or  is there an easier way to do it.

**In-Depth **
I made a quick html code for my first question and made multiple form of 'number'. It's incomplete... I decide to test one 'number' before implementing the code for the whole form
This is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["order"]["cappuccino_qty"].value;
    if (x >= 0 || x < 0);
    {
    alert("The following must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    }
    </script>   
    <body>              
    <form action = "test.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return validateForm()" name ="order">
                <label class = "field" for = "Cappucino">Cappuccino
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$3.75" name = "cappuccino_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <label class = "field" for = "Espresso">Espresso
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$3.00" name = "espresso_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <label class = "field" for = "Double Espresso">Double Espresso
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$4.25" name = "double_espresso_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <label class = "field" for = "Flat White">Flat White
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$3.75" name = "flat_white_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <label class = "field" for = "Latte">Latte  
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$3.50" name = "latte_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <label class = "field" for = "Ice Coffee">Ice Coffee
                <input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "$2.50" name = "ice_qty" size = "2"/><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit"/>
                <p>
       </form>
       </body>  
       </head>
       </Html>
```

Comment: `if (!/^\d+$/.test(x)) {...}`

Comment: You are never calling the function to do the check, that's why the code is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (x==null || x=="")
```

to

```
if (/[^\d\.]/.test(x))
```

That checks for any non-numerical or period characters (assuming you want to allow decimals).

[Edit]

See updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5UxGp/1/

Comment: It does work - try it in the console: `if (/[^\d\.]/.test("asd")) alert('not num');`

Comment: what does x represent?

Comment: I tried your code and it works!! But my only problem is now that even though the 'number' has a value it gives me an alert pop out...I'm sorry I am really new to Javascript

Comment: Using my code, the alert should fire only if the value contains characters other than numbers and dots. If you're getting weird behaviour, set up a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Its my first time using Js Fiddle so I don't really know what I am doing but here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/anon_2000/5UxGp/

Comment: You need to look into concepts such as event binding and strings vs. variables (you put "x" in quotes, which means it will be tested as a string, rather than the `x` variable. See my update Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5UxGp/1/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form_name"]["number_name"].value;
if (!(x >= 0) || !(x < 0))
  {
  alert("The following must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

By the way if 0 is minimum in your form

```
 function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["form_name"]["number_name"].value;
    if (!(x >= 0))
      {
      alert("The following must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please return true if ok

Answer (score 0):

You are only testing the variable if it is null or empty but when you input characters on it it jump out on your if statement. Try using this function. See reference here if needed: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric). Hope that helps.

```
function isNumber(x) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(x)) && isFinite(x);
}
```